# Mongodb connection timeout issue

Tags: mongodb

I have the code like below, when I try it in studio 3t, it connects. But I am getting connection timeout error in visual studio code, what is the reason?

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const databaseUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const databaseName = 'node';

mongoClient.connect(databaseUrl, (error, result) => {
   
  if(error){
    return console.log("Db Not connect.. "+error);
   }

   console.log("Db Connected..");
   const db = result.db(databaseName);
   
});
```

I tried connecting to the database. And I'm trying to bawl.

Comment: It should work. Check your connection string for typos.

Answer (score -1):

Your connection string does not have set timeout values. https://bobcares.com/blog/mongodb-connection-timeout/
Studio3t sets some by default. Maybe that's why.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).